# How to open a file resource with rapture-io?

Tags: scala, rapture.io

I would have expected this to work, but it does not.

```
import rapture.uri._
import rapture.io._

val file = uri"file:///testFile.txt"
```

It fails to compile with the following error:

```
not found: value File
val file = uri"file:///testFile.txt"
           ^
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you also need to depend on rapture-fs like so:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.propensive" %% "rapture-fs" % "0.10.0"
```

Then import the following:

```
import rapture.fs._
import platform.posix
```